# Union Zero Initialization with clang vs gcc

Tags: c, gcc, initialization, clang, unions

Given the following C code:

```
union Test {
  struct {
    int f1;
    int f2;
  };

  struct {
    int f3;
    int f4;
    int f5;
  };
};

union Test test = {.f1 = 1, .f2 = 2};
```

When I compile this with gcc 6.1.1 `f5` will be zero initialized. When I do with clang 3.8.0 it is not. I tried with `-O0` and `-O2` for both compilers which did not make any difference. This is on Linux x64.

Which is the correct behavior and can I tell clang to behave like gcc in this case? Reason is I try to compile some code with clang that assumes zero initialization in this case.

**Update**

Since the answers so far cite C11. Were there any changes in the standard that changed the behavior in later versions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[C11](http://www.compsci.hunter.cuny.edu/~sweiss/resources/c11standard.pdf#page=63) specifies at section 6.2.6.1.7 :

> When a value is stored in a member of an object of union type, the bytes of the object
>   representation that do not correspond to that member but do correspond to other members
>   take unspecified values.

You access the union via the first struct, accessing members of the second struct can produce unspecified values, so clang is not wrong neither is gcc.

---

Update: anonymous members were added in C11. Designated inits appeared in C99.

Comment: Any reference on this being true in case of initialization also?

Comment: I updated the question: Did that maybe changed in C11 and gcc defaults to another standard than clang?

Comment: @SouravGhosh : initialization is storing a value. In fact, at section 6.7.9.9 :
>Except where explicitly stated otherwise, for the purposes of this subclause unnamed members of objects of structure and union type do not participate in initialization. Unnamed members of structure objects have indeterminate value even after initialization.